# Don't you know minSdkVersion for GoogleAnalyticsV2?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-analytics

My app supports Android 1.5 (API3) to 4.1.2 (API16). When I've added GoogleAnalyticsV2 and retest it - it get errors with API3 in emulator:

```
11-08 20:00:58.813: E/dalvikvm(732): Could not find method
android.content.pm.PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName, referenced
from method
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.fillAppParameters 11-08
20:00:58.887: W/dalvikvm(732): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
226: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getInstallerPackageName
(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; 11-08 20:00:58.925:
W/dalvikvm(732): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x000c 11-08
20:00:58.934: W/dalvikvm(732): VFY:  rejected
Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/GAThread;.fillAppParameters
(Ljava/util/Map;)V 11-08 20:00:58.934: W/dalvikvm(732): Verifier
rejected class Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/GAThread; 11-08
20:00:58.964: D/AndroidRuntime(732): Shutting down VM 11-08
20:00:58.964: W/dalvikvm(732): threadid=3: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70) 11-08 20:00:58.985:
E/AndroidRuntime(732): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to
uncaught exception 11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):
java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread
11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics.<init>(GoogleAnalytics.java:55)
11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(GoogleAnalytics.java:91)
11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.setContext(EasyTracker.java:309)
11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at
com.tonycode.primenumbers.ListNumsActivity.onCreate(ListNumsActivity.java:32)
11-08 20:00:59.084: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at
...
```

While test on real devices Android 2.3.3 and Android 4.0.3 get's Ok.

In the log above I've found that Analytics Couldn't start because the method
android.content.pm.PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName isn't present in API3, it present only in [API5][http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String][1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String)

So, could you help me - 
(1) Is there any way to enable GoogleAnalyticsV2 in API3 and API4 ?
(2) If not, how can I disable GoogleAnalyticsV2 in code if the app installed on API3/4?

Comment: It is not mentioned on GoogleAnalytics site, but is it realy that GA requires API5+ ? Any ideas how to enable it on API3 & API4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Google Analytics only for API 5+ by checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
    // Start Google Analytics...
}
```

**EDIT**:

Prior to API 4, `SDK_INT` didn't exist. You can use the slightly-less-convenient [`RELEASE` value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE) (a String), though, which will work on all Android builds. Some simple parsing of the `RELEASE` value should solve your problem:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.5") == false) {
    // Start Google Analytics...
}
```

If you decide to support earlier API levels than 3 (Android 1.5), then you'll need to filter them out as well.

Comment: Oops, it works only with API4, API3 gets: "Verifier error: VFY: unable to resolve static field 34 (SDK_INT) in Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;" in run-time.

Comment: Oops, indeed! I've updated my answer to include code that should work on API 3+.